# When create PDF with ITextSharp, page is breakdown - Asp.Net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, itext, html-to-pdf

I have a UI Panel called "pnlPerson" which produces the following HTML:

```
<table width="90%" style="border: 1px black solid">
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: dodgerblue; color: white" colspan="12">GARANTİ : </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I then want to turn this HTML into a PDF using iText

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
pnlPerson.RenderControl(hw);
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();

Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

It creates the PDF, but without inline CSS properties, so the PDF page is split. How can I solve that problem?

Comment: Try adding absolute paths for the css files in the HTML you are rendering as a PDF.  E.g.  <link href="C:\MyAppLocation\Content\CSS\My.css" rel="stylesheet" /> ... or http://localhost/myapplocation/Content/Css/my.css

Comment: The `HTMLWorker` class has been deprecated for a long time. It has been designed for a specific use case and supports only very basic html.

Comment: Consider using pdfHTML. It's the modern version of HTMLWorker, and supports a much richer set of HTML5 and CSS3.